# Converting strings to float in logstash

Tags: variables, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I used

```
filter {
    mutate {
        convert => { 
            "Availability"  => "float" 
        }
    }
}
```

to convert some fields to float in the .csv file in logstash. I don't get any error but I don't get the expected output which is the strings are not converting to float.I tried this format as well

```
grok {
   match => [ "Basic", " %{NUMBER:Basic:float}"]
}
```

(Note that grok method is a sample which I have been done here, I mean not the correct way of converting strings to float)

Comment: Can you show a sample log line and what value of expect?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this behavior before. In my case, the fields I was attempting to type-cast were also being used by another type. Those fields were not getting type-cast. As I was using daily rotating indexes, when the uncast field hit the index first the field-type was `string`. When the cast field hit the index first, it was `integer`.

If this is your problem, there are two ways to solve it:

1. Hunt through your field-data and find out all the cases where `Availability` is used. Type-cast them the way you cast this one.
2. Force the issue, by updating the ElasticSearch template for your logstash indices to cast that field to `float` at index-creation time. The strings coming in will be forced to `float` or dropped.

Comment: I'll try this and see

Comment: sysadmin1138 It didn't work for me, no other solution right?

Comment: @Sheron I'm afraid those are my biggest hammers here. The rest is detective work, and I'm not sure where to point you next. Sorry!